# Action based on return of grep

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to know how to execute a shell command and based on the return, execute another command.

I only have this command to play with right now and getting nowhere.

```
grep "data" `ls -tr | tail -1`
```

alone this works fine, and greps 'data' in the latest timestamped file.
I know I need an if statement and condition but my structures are not working, please can you show me the best way to do this.

So to reiterate, I want to be able to grep the latest file in a folder and based on the found return from the grep in my case 'data' execute another command, which in my case is:

```
ping google.com > ping.txt
```

my file structure is .../test/test_files/test.1.txt

and I need to run the script from .../test/ location.

my test1.txt file looks like:

```
send data ping
```

I also need to exclude the search of the actual script I'm running, so will be using --exclude=myscript.sh.

Taken from amdixon answer and rejigged a little this works.

```
#!/bin/bash

last_file=$(ls -tr ../test/test_files/* | tail -1);
grep -r "data" --exclude=test1.txt "$last_file" 1>/dev/null;

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  printf "found..\n";
  ping google.com > googlestack.txt
else
  printf "not found..\n";
fi
```

//Bubs.

Comment: can you show what you tried? Or at least what format the line that grep will return looks like?  There are quite a few ways to do what you ask ...

Comment: so do you want to grep for data in the last file or grep for data in the file listing ?

Comment: my file structure is .../test/test_files/test.1.txt

Comment: i want to execute the .sh file from .../test

Comment: sorry I meant the structure of the line in test.1.txt file which contain data.  If it is simply the presence of the word `data` in the file, then the answer from Wiliam Pursell below should be good.

Comment: line 1 in test1.txt = send data ping

Comment: ...yes William's answer is fine but the script will just run once, upon finding 'data' execute the cmd and fi ...i need it to keep running and when found 'data' execute command ...and keep grep'ing for other detections of 'data' ...i know this is addition to the question but would be greatly appreciated in knowing the structure to do this correctly.

Comment: clarified the question.

Comment: if the script works fine for one shot, just use `cron` to schedule it at the interval you want. `man cron` is your friend if you want it to run every so many minutes/hours etc ...  If you want sub-minute checks, you will have to create your own loop like this:
 `while true; do .... call your script here ...; sleep 10s; done` 

But cron is nicer ...

Comment: Thanks tgo you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the /* in the path works fine now.
Thx for all your help especially amdixson!!

```
#!/bin/bash

last_file=$(ls -tr ../test/test_files/* | tail -1);
grep -r "data" --exclude=test1.txt "$last_file" 1>/dev/null;

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  printf "found..\n";
  ping google.com > googlestack.txt
else
 printf "not found..\n";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an if:

```
if grep data "$(ls -tr | tail -1)"; then
  cmd  # some command to execute if the file matches
else
  cmd # command to execute if the file does not match
fi
```

Notice that you've put the double quotes in exactly the wrong place: 'data' is not subject to field splitting since it contains no whitespace, but the string generated by the process substitution is subject to field splitting so it must be quoted.

Comment: Sir you code will execute the cmd even if the the string is not found?  ...I'm using an obscure string to grep for.

Comment: I think I know where I'm going wrong ...the code is searching the actual script that is why it is always found and since it is the newest file it will be searched. that is why I require to know how to execute this script two branches up or to exclude the script in the grep process.

Answer (score 1):

To find the latest entry in current dir [without using ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
#!/bin/bash

unset -v latest
dir="."

for file in "$dir"/*; do
  [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest="$file"
done

echo "Latest: $latest"
```

Source: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Answer (score 0):

I think "xargs" is also good way as below：
I create a directory "test"that contains 3 files.
test
├── t1
├── t2
└── t3
execute below command to delte all the file

```
find test/t* -print|xargs rm -rf
```

now all the file has been deleted.